# Divide Mobile Device height in percent

Tags: web-applications, mobile, height

I use Jquery Mobile Grid layout for my Web Application.
I want to divide the height of device/mobile in 5 section's.
I try to change using height in percentage but it not work, it conflict with Jquery Mobile Structure's CSS.

How i can detect mobile/device's height and get that value to pass in CSS?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript: [Window Screen](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp). But you won't be able to pass it to your CSS. However, if you are familiar with JQuery, you know you can change CSS dynamically.